# Apache Cassandra - Как создать пользователя с правами только по чтению определённых таблиц?

Tags: cassandra

Как создать пользователя с правами только по чтению определённых таблиц.

```
create role noname with password ''
```

Comment: В этот вопрос следует включить больше подробностей и уточнить проблему

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Не могу разобраться как в кассандре создать пользователя с правами только по чтению  нескольких таблиц.

Answer (score 2):

Команда [GRANT](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/4.0/cassandra/cql/security.html#grant-permission-statement) даёт возможность управлять правами пользователя. Для чтения нужно право на `SELECT`.

Например:

```sql
GRANT SELECT TO TABLE mykeyspace.mytable TO noname;
```

Ключевое слово `TABLE` опционально, его можно не писать.

Answer (score 0):

CREATE ROLE testuser WITH PASSWORD = 'password' AND LOGIN = true;

CREATE KEYSPACE testkeyspace WITH REPLICATION = {'class':'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'dc1' : 3};

GRANT ALL ON KEYSPACE testuser TO testkeyspace;

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).